# IntelliJ doesn't trigger nodejs filewatcher on mac - is there a workaround?

Tags: mac, node.js, intellij-idea

I'm working on an application that relies heavily on nodejs' filewatchers.

Now we found that IntelliJ's auto-save feature that writes to a file as you type / blur the window doesn't trigger nodejs filewatchers - at least not on mac.

The following simple test verifies this.

- Create a file called file.txt
- Create the following script in the same folder
- Edit file.txt in IntelliJ or Webstorm
- Nothing should be looked (where as if you edit the file in any other editor and save it you see change 0, change 1 etc.)

```
fs = require( "fs" );
i = 0;

fs.watch( "./file.txt", function(){
    i++;
    console.log( "change " + i );
});
```

Is there any workaround / way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

1. Right-click your script and choose `Run <my script>.js`
2. Edit your txt file and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
3. See the result in `Run Tool` window

Comment: That works for the very first change, but subsequent changes don't trigger the filewatcher anymore

Comment: works for me - all changes trigger the watcher (if I keep it running, of course)

Comment: Hm. On mac or windows? This seems to be a mac only problem. Also are you using IntelliJ or Webstorm?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the safe write functionnality. I had the same problem and disabling it solved it.
You'll find it in Settings / System Settings[image]